# FileNotFoundError The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, python-3.x, thumbnails

I'm trying to generate a thumbnail with Python. But, I'm facing an error that says the file cannot be specified. The MP4 video that I want to use in available in the same directory.
Using the following code:

```
import requests
import ffmpeg
import sys
import os

in_filename = "ddd.mp4"
out_filename = "THUMBNAIL.jpg"


def generate_thumbnail(in_filename, out_filename):
    probe = ffmpeg.probe(in_filename)
    time = float(probe["streams"][0]["duration"]) // 2
    width = probe["streams"][0]["width"]
    try:
        (
            ffmpeg.input(in_filename, ss=time)
                .filter("scale", width, -1)
                .output(out_filename, vframes=1)
                .overwrite_output()
                .run(capture_stdout=True, capture_stderr=True)
        )
    except ffmpeg.Error as e:
        print(e.stderr.decode(), file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(1)


generate_thumbnail(in_filename, out_filename)
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Job/ExTrac_Chat_DB/Thumbnail FFMPEG.py", line 27, in <module>
    generate_thumbnail(in_filename, out_filename)
  File "D:/Job/ExTrac_Chat_DB/Thumbnail FFMPEG.py", line 11, in generate_thumbnail
    probe = ffmpeg.probe(in_filename)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\practice\lib\site-packages\ffmpeg\_probe.py", line 20, in probe
    p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\practice\lib\subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\practice\lib\subprocess.py", line 1311, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Any thoughts on how to solve it?

Comment: Did you install ffmpeg?

Comment: @9769953 for sure.

Comment: To be clear: I mean the binary, not the Python package. But given that you use Conda, I am guessing Conda will have taken care of installing both.

Comment: Have you tried providing an absolute path to the input file?

Comment: @9769953 Yes I tried. Not working.

Comment: For this variable `in_filename = "ddd.mp4"` try giving absolute path of the video ..

Comment: Which ffmpeg Python package did you install?

Comment: @9769953 ffmpeg-python 0.2.0

Comment: Given the traceback, it might be something like mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python/issues/373).

Comment: I noticed that the pypi version of ffmpeg-python is from 2019, while the repository has some updates from three months ago. Perhaps those updates may solve your problem.

Comment: But if it's an ffprobe issue, you'll have to try and find out how to install ffprobe. Or possibly more likely, having ffmpeg-python find the appropriate ffmpeg binaries.

Answer (score 0):

You have to place `ffmpeg.exe` file ([Download FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html)) at the same directory as the python file (.py).